Bitbucket pipeline dotnet restore can't find projects
My bitbucket pipeline fails because it cannot find the csproj files in the project structures. Locally the project restores and builds fine using .Net 8, and the project structure is the same in bitbucket as it is locally. Here is my yaml file:
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0

pipelines:
  branches:    
    main:
      - step:
          name: Restore and Build
          script:
            - dotnet restore ./src/*.sln
      - step:
          name: Build and store binaries
          script:
            - dotnet build -c Release ./src/*.sln      
          artifacts:
            paths:
              - ./BuildingBlocks/bin/**
              - ./Services/**/**/bin/**


The restore step fails with:
dotnet restore ./src/*.sln

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.404/NuGet.targets(465,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/Services/Basket/Basket.API/basket.API.csproj" was not found. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/eshopmicroservices.sln]

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.404/NuGet.targets(465,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.Api/Catalog.csproj" was not found. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/eshopmicroservices.sln]

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.404/NuGet.targets(465,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/BuildingBlocks/BuildingBlocks.csproj" was not found. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/eshopmicroservices.sln]

(I know about the naming inconsistencies).
The yaml file exists in my Eshop folder and the structure is as follows:
-Eshop
   - eshopmicroservices.sln
   -src
      -BuildingBlocks
            - BuildingBlocks.csproj
      -Services
          - Catalog
               - Catalog.Api
                    - Catalog.csproj
          - Basket
               - Basket.API
                     - Basket.Api.csproj
  
                

Anyone familiar with this error in bitbucket? Or am I simply overlooking something in my yaml or project structure?

Do you run the exact same command locally from the root directory? Ie dotnet restore ./src/*.sln. Also, make sure your file / folder name casing matches exactly with the paths defined in your solutions; Pipelines runs a linux image which has a case-sensitive filesystem

Your YAML isn't valid either. You need a space between the array entry identifier - and whatever follows it
